# Declaring instance variables in helper methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller **before_filter** that redirects non-admin users to the root path, if they attempt to update someone else's profile:

```
before_filter :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
....
private
  def correct_user
    @user=User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user) || current_user.admin?
  end
```

I'm using this filter in two different controllers, and I want to **DRY** up the code.

My specs still pass when I move the method into **application_helper.rb**, but I'm weary of assigning the `@user` variable in a helper file. Can any harm come from this? Should I at least be delegating the assignment of the variable to a private method in the helper?

Is it better to have code duplication in this instance, or is my solution safe enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move your correct_user method into your application controller and then you can use in any of the controller with before_filter.